# How do I flatten lists containing two strings and another list by one level?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have an extensive list of lists where each contains two strings and another list with numbers:

```
lists = [
    ['A0A 4L0', 'ABBY', [38.065, 38.74, 61.987, 27.375, 105.675, 37.578]], 
    ['A0A 0A7', 'JOHN', [38.196, 39.222, 60.804, 24.139, 99.158, 31.609]],
]
```

I would like to flatten it into a list of lists containing just the strings and numbers, for example:

```
result = [
    ['A0A 4L0', 'ABBY', 38.065, 38.74, 61.987, 27.375, 105.675, 37.578], 
    ['A0A 0A7', 'JOHN', 38.196, 39.222, 60.804, 24.139, 99.158, 31.609],
]
```

I have tried using list comprehension and `itertools.chain()`, and neither one of these options flattened the list.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use:

```
result = [[el1, el2, *el3] for el1, el2, el3 in lists]
```

And the output will be:

```
[['A0A 4L0', 'ABBY', 38.065, 38.74, 61.987, 27.375, 105.675, 37.578],
 ['A0A 0A7', 'JOHN', 38.196, 39.222, 60.804, 24.139, 99.158, 31.609]]
```

Comment: Did this answer help you? If so can you consider accepting one of the available answers?

Answer (score 0):

your desired result is not fully flattened.

you can use a custom function to flatten the list.

```py
def flatten(x: list) -> list:
    res = []
    for i in x:
        res.extend(flatten(i) if isinstance(i, list) else [i])
    return res
```

to fully flatten your list, you can do:

```py
print(flatten(lists))
```

which will give you:

```py
['A0A 4L0', 'ABBY', 38.065, 38.74, 61.987, 27.375, 105.675, 37.578, 'A0A 0A7', 'JOHN', 38.196, 39.222, 60.804, 24.139, 99.158, 31.609]
```

to get your desired result:

```py
print([flatten(i) for i in lists])
```

which will give you:

```py
[
    ['A0A 4L0', 'ABBY', 38.065, 38.74, 61.987, 27.375, 105.675, 37.578], 
    ['A0A 0A7', 'JOHN', 38.196, 39.222, 60.804, 24.139, 99.158, 31.609],
]
```

you can add tuple to conditions if you also want to flatten tuples:

```py
import typing

def flatten(x: list) -> list:
    res = []
    for i in x:
        res.extend(flatten(i) if isinstance(i, typing.Union[list,tuple]) else [i])
    return res
```